# dsl router for bridging two lans

Tags: router, vlan, bridge, dsl

I have two office locations that each have DSL service. I have the routers set up so that the two subnets, 10.0.1.x and 10.0.2.x, correctly keep data on each subnet and or pass across to the other subnet as needed. However, I would like to have my telephones connect across the internet link. The phones use MAC addressing, so I need to bridge the packets for the phones across the internet link. The offices are small, so bridging everything would be OK, too.  I have been searching around and have found key phrases "remote bridging" "concurrent routing/bridging" and "integrated routing/bridging", but, I'm not sure I'm in the right search space.

Is what I want to do feasible? What search terms might I use. I'm willing to buy dsl routers for both ends to make this happen.

I'll admit to being a dufus using 10.x.x.x address space. I just liked the number 10 more than 192, but now that I realize most equipment expects the DHCP server in the 192.168.x.x address space I'll know better next time. I'm all static IP addresses in my setup, fwiw.

Comment: So the phones *can't* use IP addresses to communicate? They're L2 only? That would be quite unusual.

Comment: Yeah, they are Talkswitch brand. There is hardware for IP connections if I put talkswitch server at each end. I'm interested in having my main office having the talkswitch main device. The secondary office jsut needs a couple of phones. Since the phones are MAC addressed on the LAN it made sense that I could set up a bridge to the other office and the remote phones should work well. Data usage on the network is low, so the DSL should be OK for the phones at the remote site.

Comment: Needs EoIP, perhaps?